# Bootstrap Modal not showing without fade class

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm really confused about this ... I'm using bootstrap 4 and I want a non-animated (fading) modal on the official website it says to remove the "fade" class, so I removed it, but it stopped working, the modal div that doesn't appear after that and still adds the "display: none" when I click the button.

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#mobileMessageBox" data-toggle="modal" type="button" onclick="getTalkCQSP(this)">TEST</button>

<div id="mobileMessageBox" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true"
    style="max-height: 100vh; ">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you included all necessary CSS and JS files of Bootstrap? custom CSS styles which are hiding the modal? - can't reproduce with your code.

Comment: yes... like with fade class works, i have this: jquery-3.4.1.min.js, bootstrap-grid.css, bootstrap.css, bootstrap-reboot.css, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.bundle.js

Comment: yeah u can't run this code because a function in onclick, just remove it. And no, I search for any modal selector in my css and js customs files and i can't find anything, so... i can't understand why this not work

Comment: I have tried with and without the fade class and it's not working either way, so the problem is not about removing the fade class

Comment: Maybe you don't see the modal because there is no content?

Comment: what? really? but it works for me with fade. I have content the function onclick, insert content there

Comment: with or without the fade class, the display:block is applying correctly

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include all necessary [CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#css) and [JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js) files of Bootstrap:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Note:** Also make sure you don't hide the modal with own custom CSS.

Using all the CSS and JavaScript files your given example is working:

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-target="#mobileMessageBox" data-toggle="modal" type="button" onclick="getTalkCQSP(this)">TEST</button>

<div id="mobileMessageBox" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true"
     style="max-height: 100vh; ">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body p-0">Hello
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap.bundle.js is the problem, I couldn't use modal because it